# ASP.NET Routing - capture entire url with constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to set up a `route` that will match on any `url`, with a constraint. This is what I have tried:

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase("CatchAll Content Validation", "{*url}",
    new { controller = "Content", action = "LoadContent" },
    new { url = new ContentURLConstraint(), }
);
```

and for testing purposes I have the following simple constraint:

```
public class ContentURLConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var s = (string)values["url"];
        return s.Contains("comm");              
    }
}
```

If the constraint is satisfied I when expect to pass the full url to the controll action LoadContent

```
public ActionResult LoadContent(string url)
{
   return Content(url);
}
```

I am expecting, when I load a page, for **`s`** in the `Match` function to contain the entire `url`, so that I can check it, but instead it is `null`.  What might I be missing?

Comment: Not fully clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you maybe update your question with some examples?

Comment: I've added some more detail. In short, I want to check all incoming urls against the constraint, and pass the full url along to the Action if satisfied. The Match function shown is just for illustrating the problem I am having.

Comment: Show us what the `values` object looks like within the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `null` when there is no `url` in the route, i.e. host itself: http://localhost:64222.

When there is a url, e.g.: http://localhost:64222/one/two, your `url` parameter will hold a value: `one/two`.

You can modify your constraint to something like:

```
public class ContentURLConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values routeDirection)
    {
        var url = values[parameterName] as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            return url.Contains("comm");
        }

        return false; // or true, depending on what you need.
    }
}
```

> What might I be missing?

Could be that you are missing that url constraint does not contain host, port, schema and query string. If you need it - you can get it from `httpContext.Request`.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you.